# Add auto-complete with non-standard builtins w/Visual Studio Code/JS

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, duktape

Visual studio code seems to have good support for javascript autocomplete, but I have a project which uses duktape to export a large and growing library of objects from my application.

The library is growing quite quickly as more functionality gets exported, and I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow import or make VS code's intellisense aware of a set of "built in" objects.  These objects have no source per-se.  They're exported via duktape's API calls.  I can traverse over the global object space and dump the names of all known objects and print them formatted any arbitrary way.

I'm looking for a way to make the global object dump (again, it can worked into any format) useful to intellisense or any other autocomplete engine.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar project ongoing and had exactly the same need. The solution is easy: create a typings file for your app and put it into `node_modules/@type/<yourid>`. If you don't know about typings files read up on the [Definitely Typed](http://definitelytyped.org/) page. On the welcome page there's another way to reference a typings file, if you don't have a node.js structure:

```
/// <reference path="<path>/yourtypes.d.ts" />
```

The typings file also works for plain JS code, if you give vscode some hints via type annotations. That looks like:

```
/** @type {yourmodule.yourtype} */
var value; // Will be considered as being of type `yourtype`.
```

With that in place vscode will then show members for `value` in the code completion list.

Comment: I was able to get this to work, in as much as I can include additional global types - the problem now is I get all the default node ES6 globals and types included into intellisense by default, most of which aren't relevant within a duktape environment.   How can I tell VSCode "I only want to use these specific .d.ts files"?

Comment: To my knowledge you cannot *exclude* typings files.

Comment: That does seem quite an oversight - it seems to assume that you'd only ever use the full standard libraries when coding, and not be using a slimline environment like duktape

Comment: I had no need to. The additional suggestions rarely got in the way and because I added a Node.js like environment on top of duktape the help for the "real" Node.js was pretty helpful and hence welcome.